# Cancel a jquery submit() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a form which calls an ajax post, using the `submit()` jquery method:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myform').submit(function(){
      submitFunction(); /* does and Ajax post */
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
<form id="myform" action="thisaction" method="post">
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Now, the thing is, when that Ajax post succeeds, I want to cancel the jquery `override` of my form submission, in order to let it do its normal action (`thisaction`). I already tried this :

```
/* Inside submitFunction() */

$.ajax({

  /* random data... */

  success: function(jsonData)
           {
              $('#mylogin').submit(function(){
                ;
              });
           }
});
```

But when I debug it, the `submitFunction()` is still called after the second submission... How do I disable this and let a `normal` HTTP post to `thisaction` occur?

Comment: May this help `e.preventDefault(); return false;` ?

Comment: set an flag , and second time just check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the submit handler, before the `submitFunction()`:

```
$(this).off('submit')
```

And in the ajax success callback:

```
$('#myform').submit();
```

This will unbind the submit handler that returns false and re-submit the form when the ajax callback is called.

You can also try `.one()` to bind a handler that will only be executed once:

```
$('#myform').one('submit', function() {...
```

Comment: We have a winner! I still don't really understand what "$('#myform').submit();" does, but it works. I would think it would automatically submit the form without waiting for user input... but it does wait, and that's the exact behavior I wanted.

Comment: @BraveKenny `.submit()` triggers the submit event, wich is basically the same as native `form.submit()` but jQuery adds some features like bubbling and compabiblity fixes.

Comment: Yeah... Actually this .submit() action triggers the submit in Internet Explorer. I need to find a more compatible solution.

Comment: Regarding your second option, .one(), won't this cause a problem if the user input is wrong on the first time? I want to change the submit only when the ajax post succeed AND responds with an "okay" answer. If the user inputs wrong data, I want to let him try again.

Comment: Okay, so actually your second solution works better. I put it twice in the code: once instead of the first one, and the second in my "incorrect user input" case. That way each time the user fails, I re-bind the submission one more time, until the response is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to unbind the event.

```
$('#mylogin').submit(function(){
  $(this).unbind("submit");
});
```

Here the documentation http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: That seemed interesting, but submissions still call submitFunction() after this.